# save all config VS access configObj for each field

Tags: python, python-2.7, configobj

I have a config file abc.ini with trivial fields

```
[SET_1]
a=1
b=2
c=3

[SET_2]
d=4
e=5
```

Now, in the script(python) I can do 2 things:

1. Access the file abc.ini once and save all config in a data structure
2. Access the each field where I need them as configObj[SET_1][a] etc

> Which of these is more efficient and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ConfigObj section actually inherits from a Python `dict`, so both approaches will actually use the same underlying data structure. There will be no difference in performance.